# Match any string in the format (+-)(digit or letter)(colon)

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to find any string that matches the format: a '+' or a '-', followed by a number or a letter, followed by a colon ':'.

Example:

`"+2: Each player discards a card.\n−X: Return target nonlegendary creature card with converted mana cost X from your graveyard to the battlefield.\n−8: You get an emblem with \"Whenever a creature dies, return it to the battlefield under your control at the beginning of the next end step.\"`

Should match "+2:", "-X:" and "-8:".

I've done `/[0-9a-z]:/i` but I can't match the plus and minus.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! That did match strings with plus sign but not strings with minus.

Comment: the `−` in your text is a em dash, not a minus character

Comment: @catcon That is a [`‎2212 MINUS SIGN`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E2%88%92), it is not an em-dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
$re = '/[−+-]?[0-9a-z]:/iu';
$str = '+2: Each player discards a card.\\n−X: Return target nonlegendary creature card with converted mana cost X from your graveyard to the battlefield.\\n−8: You get an emblem with \\"Whenever a creature dies, return it to the battlefield under your control at the beginning of the next end step.';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/eaBKk)

The `[−+-]?` part matches an optional `−`, `-` or `+` chars.

If you want to support any other "minus" looking chars, use

```
$re = '/[−+\p{Pd}]?[0-9a-z]:/iu';
```

The `\p{Pd}` matches dash punctuation chars, but not the `−` char, unfortunately.

Comment: That works! :D Is there a way I could wrap only the "`-` and `+` followed by a digit or letter" with curly brackets?

Comment: @PietroBonfim No idea what you mean, so, no, you can't.

Comment: Replace so the string becomes: `"{+2}: Each player discards a card.\n{−X}: Return..."`

Comment: Got it by grouping `([−+-]?[0-9a-z]):`. Thanks!

Comment: @PietroBonfim You should have explained what you are doing in the question, you would have got the right answer instantly. `preg_replace('~([−+-]?[0-9a-z])(:)~ui', '{$1}$2', $s)`, see [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/btkQR).

Comment: @PietroBonfim Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.